# nested select statement with SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to know if its possible to write a nested select statment?

I have the following which calculates the booked time:

```
SELECT description, SUM(ts.booked_time) AS booked_time_total, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @testDate, 106) AS month_name, @week_ref AS week_ref
FROM timesheets ts

WHERE @testDate <= convert(datetime, end_dtm, 120) and 
      dateadd(wk, 1, @testDate) > convert(datetime, start_dtm, 120)
```

But the booked time appears to be wrong. Isnt the SUM supposed to calculate the total for each row which are within the start_dtm and end_dtm. So if I have 10 rows with 1 in the booked time you would expect the SUM to be 10.

test data:

[image]

Comment: upload some data and desirted result.

Comment: Your question is tagged sql-server, but your query is not valid syntax for MS SQL Server. Specifically, you have column "description" in the SELECT clause without a corresponding GROUP BY. What database platform are you using?

Comment: Your code cannot work. There has to be a GROUP BY clause to do aggregates like SUM, unless all the other fields are based entirely on the variables. You included [description] so you have to group on it.

Comment: as @RoyiNamir said post some desired results with sample data, your screenshot above doen't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUM` calculates the total value of the fields while `COUNT` is the total number of records.

```
SELECT description, 
       COUNT(ts.booked_time) AS booked_time_total, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @testDate, 106) AS month_name, 
       @week_ref AS week_ref
FROM timesheets ts
WHERE @testDate <= convert(datetime, end_dtm, 120) and 
      dateadd(wk, 1, @testDate) > convert(datetime, start_dtm, 120)
```

Comment: so if i have 5 rows with 2 in the booked time it will only display 5 which is wrong. I need SUM.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking to use COUNT rather than SUM.

Comment: SUM adds up values of the columns. COUNT will actually count the rows.